# StartActivityForResults always returns RESULT_CANCELLED for Intent.ACTION_SEND

Tags: android, start-activity

As the share pop up appears, I shared the content on WhatsApp successfully, but still returns RESULT_CANCELLED. Same result when I send a email using Gmail.

Calling Sharing intent, `ACTION_SEND` with `startActivityForResult` always returns `CANCELLED`

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Taxeeta, Cab Around The Curb");
    sharingIntent
        .putExtra(
            android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                "Hiring a cab no longer needs you to wait on call centers, or pay a"
                + " convenience (yeah right!!) charge. Taxeeta connects you"
                + " to drivers directly, for a quick book experience. With Taxeeta"
                + " you can take matters in your own hands (literally). To download"
                + " the app for your phone visit http://www.taxeeta.com");
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share and earn a extra Priviledge"), 111);
```

ActivityForResult Code

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 111) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Ok DUDE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Oversmart Eh!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 42):

`startActivityForResult()` only works with activities that are intended to be called that way. If the activity you are calling doesn't explicitly return a result, you will get the default result RESULT_CANCELED. Obviously `ACTION_SEND` is not designed to be called this way. The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND) for `ACTION_SEND` indicates that is generates no output (ie: generates no result).

See the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int,%20android.os.Bundle%29) for `Activity.startActivityForResult()`:

> Note that this method should only be used with Intent protocols that
>   are defined to return a result. In other protocols (such as
>   ACTION_MAIN or ACTION_VIEW), you may not get the result when you
>   expect. For example, if the activity you are launching uses the
>   singleTask launch mode, it will not run in your task and thus you will
>   immediately receive a cancel result.

Comment: Is there a work around? If I'd like to somehow share an image and be able to tell if it was successful or not, how can I do that?

Comment: @JHowzer not that I know of. How would you define "successful" anyway? This would require cooperation between your app and the sharing app, and there is no standard for this.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and i think that the result will be always "Canceled" because even if the email is sent or no the activity will be killed.

Comment: I get this too, but I think the problem is that the email app(Gmail) needs to provide a result, which then needs to be forwarded to the Chooser which then needs to pass it to your app. I think Google didn't thought about passing the value along.