# android fragment check send mail finish(android show dialog when mail send success)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments

I have fragment. when click button,it  send mail, but i don't know when mail send success, after i show dialog success.
my code send :

```
 //Intent action send
        Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
                       new String[]{to});
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
                       "bbbbb");
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                       "AAAAAAA"));

        //need this to prompts email client only
        email.setType("message/rfc822");
        getActivity().startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email,
                                                         "Send mail..."));
```

**i want show dialog when mail send success.**
Please help me. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like there is no good solution for this.

The 'normal' way would be to use `startActivityForResult()` as you send your intent, but Intent.ACTION_SEND gives no output ([documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND)) so this doesn't work either. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16622012/startactivityforresults-always-returns-result-cancelled-for-intent-action-send).

The only way to do it for sure would be to make your own activity to send the email, and return a result from that.

Comment: it is hard in fragment