# How can get response back for third party app(Gmail/Email/Message/WhatsApp) to our app

Tags: android

How can get response back for third party app(Gmail/Email/Message/WhatsApp) to our app that message is send/cancel from there or not in our app.

I am using third party app(Gmail/Email/Message/WhatsApp)to send message.
By calling implicit intent with `Intent.ACTION_SEND` action.

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Message need to send");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Connect invitation");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{email});
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");

Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(sendIntent,"Send To");
startActivityForResult(intent, 1001);
```

From above code I always get `resultCode` 0 in `onActivityResult` for every case i.e. message are send cancel or user just back from third party app.`1001`

Comment: try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16622012/startactivityforresults-always-returns-result-cancelled-for-intent-action-send

Comment: Possible duplicate of [StartActivityForResults always returns RESULT\_CANCELLED for Intent.ACTION\_SEND](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16622012/startactivityforresults-always-returns-result-cancelled-for-intent-action-send)

Comment: That's not possible unless some app works this way .. Here you are completely depending upon some app to send result back ..